# Counting unique MAC addresses from a .pcap file

Tags: linux, terminal, packet, pcap, tcpdump

I'm trying to produce a shell command that will read a given .pcap file using tcpdump and would output the number of unique MAC addresses in the given .pcap file

Can't wrap my head around it plus the "tcp --help" is pretty useless:
So far I got this

`` tcpdump -r mypcap.pcap ether -v `dst ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` | uniq -c ``

any help would be appreciated

Comment: So I guess no one actually answered my question, I asked how to do it with tcpdump not wireshark. Even though your answers are good but they are not what was asked.

Answer (score 3):

Wireshark's TShark command-line utility will probably work better, as it allows more control over the output format of packets.

You could, for example, do

```
tshark -r mypcap.pcap -T fields -E separator=, -e eth.src -e eth.dst
```

which will, for an Ethernet capture, print, for each packet, the source and destination MAC addresses for the packets, with a comma between them.

To quote the `uniq` man page on my machine:

> Repeated lines in the input will not be detected if they are not adjacent, so it may be necessary to sort the files first.

so you should next pipe the output of `tshark` to `sort`.

However, in that case, what `sort` will be sorting, and `uniq` will be checking for uniqueness and counting with `-c`, are *pairs* of source and destination addresses.  01:02:03:04:05:06 to 06:05:04:03:02:01 will be counted as *different* from 06:05:04:03:02:01 to 01:02:03:04:05:06.  This is probably not what you want.

If you want a count of *source* MAC addresses, without caring about the *destination* MAC addresses, do

```
tshark -r mypcap.pcap -T fields -e eth.src | sort | uniq -c
```

That's *probably* the best way to determine what addresses are present on your network; a machine on your network could be sending packets to a destination address *not* on your network (and perhaps that doesn't exist anywhere on Earth or launched from Earth), so the destination addresses may not be what you want.  On the other hand, if there's a machine on your network with that destination address, and it's not bothering to send any packets on the network, it wouldn't show up if you're looking only at source addresses; however, that's unlikely to be the case, even if it's not impossible.  (It wouldn't respond to, for example, ARP packets, making it less likely, although not impossible, for other machines on your network to know about its MAC address, and thus making it less likely, although not impossible, that its MAC address would *be* a destination address.)

For *destination* MAC addresses, do

```
tshark -r mypcap.pcap -T fields -e eth.dst | sort | uniq -c
```

If you want both, you will need to use a *newline* as the separator between the source and destination address, to put them on separate lines, so `sort` will sort both source and destination addresses and `uniq` will find unique addresses.  That would be done, at least if this is being done with a Bourne-compatible shell (Bourne shell, Korn shell a/k/a ksh, Bourne-again shell a/k/a bash, etc.) with

```
tshark -r mypcap.pcap -T fields -E separator='
' -e eth.src -e eth.dst | sort | uniq -c
```

Yes, that's a newline after the first quote, and another quote immediately after the newline.

Comment: but what if a machine doesn't have wireshark and tshark installed so you have to use primitive tools like tcpdump?

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to count the number of unique Ethernet MAC addresses present in a capture file, then I agree with @user13951124 that using [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) is the better tool choice for this use case.  And here I propose an alternate solution using **tshark**'s `-z endpoints,eth` option.

For example, I have a file containing 2 unique Ethernet MAC addresses in it, and when I run the following command:

```
tshark.exe -nqr mypcap.pcap -z endpoints,eth
```

I get the following output:

```
AST modules loaded
================================================================================
Ethernet Endpoints
Filter:<No Filter>
                       |  Packets  | |  Bytes  | | Tx Packets | | Tx Bytes | | Rx Packets | | Rx Bytes |
00:26:b9:b3:ce:7a              2          1072          2            1072           0               0
00:12:17:b5:0d:32              2          1072          0               0           2            1072
================================================================================
```

If you want the count, you can pipe the output to [`wc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) and then print the result of the expression minus the number of irrelevant lines of output, which in my case is 6.  So the entire command looks like this:

```
count=$(tshark.exe -nqr mypcap.pcap -z endpoints,eth | wc -l) && echo $(( $count - 6 ))
```

And in this case, the output you get is simply:

```
2
```

My guess is that this solution would be faster because no sorting is needed and `tshark` has already provided the list of unique endpoints, so there are no duplicates to deal with either.

Comment: @user13951124 and Christopher Maynard thank you both for the explanaition and givin really great examples! The reason why I asked specificaly for tcpdump command is that for tshark you need to have wireshark installed and tcpdump is usually already present in a machine. So for example you are pen-testing a machine and need to look at the traffic and it doesn't have wireshark you will probably use tcpdump.

Answer (score 0):

My earlier solution proposed using [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) - **and I'd still recommend that solution over this one** - but if you *really* want to use [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) to solve this, then it can be done, but you will also need some help from other utilities.  The proposed solution below requires [`cut`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html), [`sed`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html), [`sort`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) and [`wc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html).

The original question asked for *"... the number of unique MAC addresses in the given .pcap file"*, so that's exactly what the following ***count_unique_macs.sh*** script does.  It requires 2 passes of the .pcap file, the first to isolate the source MACs, the second to isolate the destination MACs.  It writes them all to a temporary file then sorts them by unique MACs only.  Finally, it displays the number of lines in the file and then deletes the temporary file.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
        echo "Usage: count_unique_macs.sh <file>"
        exit 1
fi

file=$1
tmp_file=/tmp/macs
tcpdump -r $file -ne 2> /dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > $tmp_file
tcpdump -r $file -ne 2> /dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed 's/,//' >> $tmp_file
cat $tmp_file | sort -u | wc -l
rm -f $tmp_file
```